# Use a class method in router.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm really new to node.js
and I'm having trouble when I'm using a class method in router.get callback

It gives me this error:

Can you guys help me out ?

`Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object object]`

Here is my code

router.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const test = require('../controller/controller');
router.get('/', test.testing());
module.exports = router;
```

controller.js :

```
class oop
{
    testing(req,res)
    {
        console.log('okay');
    }
}
exports.testing =new oop();
```

app.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(80);
const wiki = require('./routes/router');
app.use('/', wiki);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback function will be called in some arbitrary amount of time, therefore you need to provide a reference to the function... so when the time comes, Javascript can execute that function. In your case, you are not passing the function, but running it! `test.testing()`. What you are actually passing to the 'callback' parameter is the result of `test.testing()` which, in this case, is `undefined`

Comment: You export the class ```exports.testing =new oop();``` & that whole file/object is imported under the name of 'test' ```const test = require('../controller/controller');``` when you refence the function ```test.testing()``` you should be doing ```test.testing.testing()```. Your class exists on a property of the export. Make sure  you emmit the parentheses! ```router.get('/', test.testing.testing);```